# Find the number of paths from lower left corner to upper right corner which do not cut the diagonal joining the two end points.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math, combinations

> A $8\times8$ square grid allows movement only along the left-right or up-down direction with no back tracking. If $A$ is the total number of paths from lower left corner to upper right corner and $B$ is the number of paths from lower left corner to upper right corner which do not cut the diagonal joining the two end points then find $\frac AB$

**My Attempt:**

$A=\frac{16!}{8!8!}$

$B=\frac A2$

So, $\frac AB=2$

But the answer given is $9$

Looks like my understanding of B is not correct.

I just thought we need to take those paths which are below the diagonal, so, half?

Comment: Why do you think that $B=\frac A2$?

Comment: @lulu I explained that in my last line

Comment: What you wrote doesn't make sense.  There are clearly as many paths which are above the diagonal as below...but you are forgetting all the paths which cross the diagonal (and there are a lot of those).

Comment: @lulu sorry what I wrote didn't make sense. I just thought if we don't want to cross the diagonal then only below the diagonal paths will be chosen. So, half. This must be wrong, that's why I am getting wrong answer but I don't know how to approach it correctly

Comment: There's probably a quick way to see it (given the simple answer), but unless you spot that I'd suggest working recursively.  Consider the good paths that start from any particular node.  Easy to count for the points near $(8,8)$ and then just go out from there.

Comment: Not sure that was clear:  You can restrict to paths that never get above the diagonal (by your remark) so just count those. That property is retained as you go from point to point.

Comment: This seems to be relevant: [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: @lulu thanks for the comment. I am still not able to figure it out. I'll come back to it tomorrow again.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier thanks, that's helpful. But I am not able to make sense of it fully as of now. I'll try to work on it tomorrow again.